# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
 string createddate = "10/14/2016 11:46 AM";
 DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(createddate);
```

I am trying to convert string as a datetime format it is working some devices, some devices throwing above exception. whys ? please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Most likely the culture on each device is affecting it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each device will potentially have a different [culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can ignore the culture and force it to recognize a specific date format in your string:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    createddate , "MM/dd/yy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See MSDN for [standard date string formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [custom date string formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not showing AM/PM"?  *What* isn't showing it?  The resulting date?  Dates are dates.  How they are displayed is a function of the device or application that's displaying them.  If you're talking about a watch in Visual Studio, for example, it could be that your computer is setup for some reason to show 24-hr time format.  This will become more evident if you try it with a time after 12:00 PM; 1:00 PM would be 13:00.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string createddate = "10/14/2016 11:46 AM";
   DateTime dateTime;
   DateTime.TryParse(createddate, out dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the date and time format when you convert a `string` to a `DateTime` value. *Guessing* the default format or *hoping* the format is correct will lead to diffent kind of bugs. That's one of the most common sources of the bugs which *can't be reproduced on the developer's machine*.

**Example to do it right:**

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("10/14/2016 11:46 AM", 
                               "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```